# issue on .then and .catch

Tags: javascript, passport.js

Is it possible to trigger .then AND .catch ?

here my script :

```js
passport.use(new BasicStrategy( (username, password, callback) => {
    User.findOne({where: { username: username }})
      .then(function (data) {
        if(data === null) { 
          console.log("then.false"); 
          callback(null, false);};
          var verify = data.verifyPassword(password);
          if(verify === true) { 
            console.log("then.data "+ data); 
            callback(null, data); 
          } 
          callback(null, false);
        })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log('catch  '+ err);
        callback(null, false);
      })
  })
);
```

and here my console, as we can see then and catch are triggered. How is it possible ?

```js
then.data [object SequelizeInstance:user]
catch  Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
```

Comment: If `findOne()` succeeds, you'd go in the `.then()` callback. If the `.then()` callback results in a rejection, you'd go in the next `.catch()`

Answer (score 0):

If `findOne` or anything inside the `then` throws/rejects, they'll invoke the chained `catch`. Most likely, one of your two `callback()` calls is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I changed the code like this :

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy( (username, password, callback) => {
User.findOne({where: { username: username }})
  .then(function (data) {
    var verify = data.verifyPassword(password);
    if(verify == true) { console.log("VERIFY = " + verify); callback(null, data); } 
       }
  )
  .catch( err => {
    console.log('catch  '+ err);
    callback(null, false);
    }
  )
  }
  ));
```

My console result is :

VERIFY = true
catch  Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use

We are through .then AND catch again despite a "true" from verify and an "if" returning " true too.